# Which technology changes a website to grey without affecting underlying resources?

Tags: html, css, css-filters

Due to the loss of Thailand's King Bhumibol Adulyadej, many websites in Thailand have changed to a grey theme. But when I right-click and click "open image in new tab," I see the original, color image. Even videos change color. What technology could I use for doing that?

Comment: Note: I removed your link. That site is unavailable in most countries, so it doesn't demonstrate the grayscale effect for most of this site's users.

Comment: RIP Bhumibol :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add a [CSS `filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) to the `<body>` tag. Specifically, you would add `filter: grayscale(100%);`.

Example snippet:

```css
.filtered {
  filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<p>No filter<br/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVury.png">
</p>

<p class="filtered">Filtered<br/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVury.png">
</p>
```

This will work in [nearly all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-filters), but not Internet Explorer or Opera Mini.

Answer (score 0):

This is done via CSS3. Where you can convert anything to greyscale using

```
filter:grayscale(1);
```

If you add this css to the `<body>` tag of the website this will turn entire website to gray.